# All Graphics3D commands crash

Tags: bugs, front-end, graphics3d, windows, crash

**Bug introduced in 10.2 or earlier and persisting through 11.3**

---

Recently updated from Mathematica 8.0 to 10.2 running on Windows 7 (8.0 was uninstalled before installing 10.2). Anytime a 3d graphics is rendered, the first rendering in a notebook is completely normal. The *second* rendering *always* crashes, requiring a kill process.
For example:

```
Line [1]: Graphics3D[Sphere[]]
```

Always renders correctly the first time. However, if you re-enter Line [1] *or* even enter a new line using Graphics3D (or related: Plot3D, etc), Mathematica crashes.
Here is a view of my SystemInformation[]:

[image: System Information]

I have the latest NVIDIA graphics drivers.

Question:

1. The above system information refers to DirectX 9. I have DirectX 11 installed. Is this a mistake that I should fix?
2. Is this some issue with dynamic evaluation? I turned dynamic evaluation off and I still get the crashing after a second graphics is rendered. But still..?
3. What else should I try?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Contact `support@wolfram.com` with this, please.

Comment: Tagging as bug because at least two people experience the same symptom (FE crash) due to the same cause (plugged in controller).

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and it drove me crazy for a long time.

Do you have any joysticks plugged in? Specifically, if you have a Logitech 'Extreme 3D Pro' joystick plugged in, it will cause Mathematica to crash upon interaction with any Graphics3D object.

Answer (score 4):

This is still the case in 2018 with Mathematica 11.3; if you have an USB gamepad or joystick plugged in (in my scenario some kind of standard jump and run gamepad) Mathematica will crash when calling a Graphics3D command. Unplug the joystick, and everything works fine again (thanks Dugan Hammock for the hint).